# How can I use perl for changing format of coordinates?

Tags: perl

I am beginner in Perl, I have a text file with coordinates of some places (about 400 coordinates) in terms of decimal degree, I am going to change them to degree,minute, second. My is such as below:

```
060305 1932 36.72 27.7853N 56.5446E 19.27 0.19
```

in this "27.7853" and "56.5446" are latitude and longitude respectively. I used this to extract lat. and lon. but I couldn't change format for all data in a loop.

```
my @latitude = $event =~ /\s+(\d+\.\d+)[N]{1}\s/mg;
my @longitude = $event =~ /\s(\d+\.\d+)[E]{1}\s/mg;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag! Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]. It's not entirely clear what you are having trouble with. It seems you know how to read the file line by line. Are you struggling with that regular expression (which could be done with `split` more easily) or do you not know how to _convert_ the values?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use something like [Geo::Coordinates::Transform](http://search.cpan.org/~troxel/Geo-Coordinates-Transform-0.10/lib/Geo/Coordinates/Transform.pm). It supports several coordinates formats:

- DMS Degrees:Minutes:Seconds (48 30 30, -117 30' 30")
- DM Degrees:Decimal-Minutes (48 30.5, -117 30.5'),
- DD Decimal-Degrees (48.5083333, -17.5083333)

If you do the calculations yourself though, it's not too hard if you aren't too fussy. If your input coordinates are 0 to 360 degrees (like a Greenwich hour angle) and you assume that that is the circumference of the earth (note the earth is not a perfect sphere) is 360 degrees, and each degree is 60 minutes and each minute is 60 seconds... then...

```
my $decdeg = 187.645221;
my $deg = int($decdeg);
my $min = int(($decdeg - $deg) * 60);
my $sec = int(((($decdeg - $deg) * 60) - $min) * 60);
print "$deg degrees\n";
print "$min minutes\n";
print "$sec seconds\n";
```

Will get you:

```
187 degrees
38 minutes
42 seconds
```